# What happens if the amount of characters that are entered into your character array is less than the amount of spaces you specified

Tags: c, arrays, character, project

```
char ch_arry[20] = { S, A, L, L, Y};
printf( "%s", ch_arry[] );
```

Will it fill the end of the array with null characters?

Comment: The contents of the last 15 characters are undefined.

Comment: Not so, @David.  C has no partial initialization.

Comment: Note that you need `'S', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'Y'` unless you have macros `S`, `A`, `L` and `Y` that map to integer constants suitable for use in initializing characters.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - or variables with the same names

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Just say "well I'm building in EBCDIC support" to the project manager.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: that depends on where the variable is defined.  Inside a function, yes.  At file scope — no.

Answer (score 6):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
>   initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
>   previously listed initializer for the same subobject;151) **all
>   subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized
>   implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

And

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — **if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;**
>
> **— if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,** and any padding is initialized to zero
>   bits;

So if you have a declaration like this

```
char ch_arry[20] = { 'S', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'Y'};
```

then all elements of the array that are not initialized explicitly will be initialized implicitly with zeroes.

Comment: Upvoted - I love your reference quality answers. Your copy of the standard is clearly well-thumbed.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you.:)

Comment: Also note [§6.7.9 21](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21)-- "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Answer (score 4):

The remaining 15 characters are set to `\0`. This is a useful feature of C.

Note that you need to use

```
char ch_arry[20] = { 'S', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'Y'};
```

unless you have some insane macro trickery, and

```
printf("%s", ch_arry);
```

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question.

the remaining 15 character will be assigned null value.

And you are declaring the array wrong... if you want ch_array = SALLY, you should use single inverted comma ('S' like this) with each of your character.

For output use printf("%s", ch_arry); instead of printf("%s", ch_arry[]);